# how to configure mailed by domain using SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to Add Mailed by:domain using amazon SES but i am not sure where i can configure that also i want to add parent domain(example.com) in mailed-by. please help me to solve create this. Example image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to SES console -> Configuration: Verified identities -> YOUR DOMAIN -> Edit custom MAIL FROM domain.

See example below:

[image]